# Separating different points with different colors on a scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This is a code I've written:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1 = pd.read_csv('F:\HCSE\sample_data1.csv',sep=';')
colnames = data1.columns

plt.plot(data1.iloc[:,0],data1.iloc[:,2],'bs')
plt.ylabel(colnames[2])
plt.xlabel(colnames[0])
plt.show()
```

This is the data I have used:

```
Age;Gender;LOS;WBC;HB;Nothrophil
0.62;1;0.11;9.42;22.44;70.43
0.84;0;0.37;4.4;10.4;88.4
0.78;0;0.23;6.8;15.6;76.5
0.8;0;-0.02;9.3;15.1;87
0.7;1;0.19;5.3;11.3;82
0.25;0;0.27;5.9;10.6;87.59
0.32;0;0.37;3.1;12.5;15.4
0.86;1;0.31;4.1;10.4;77
0.75;0;0.21;12.07;14.1;88
```

Finally, I have drawn the chart which can be found in the [link here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OY85U.jpg)

My questions is: How can I have different colors for different sexes (for example: male=red and female=blue)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would you mind accepting an answer, if it helped you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
cols = {0: 'red', 1: 'blue'}

plt.scatter(data1.Age, data1.LOS, c=data1.Gender.map(cols))
```

Answer (score 0):

With your dataframe as it is, you could use the built-in [`df.plot.scatter()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html) function and pass `Gender` to the `color` keyword:

```
data1.plot.scatter(
    'Age', 'LOS',
    c='Gender', cmap='RdBu',
    edgecolor='None', s=45)
```

[image]

Note that I've also removed the black borders around each point and slightly increased the size.